# How can I enable the minor grid lines in a Matlab plot?

Tags: matlab, plot

See the [documentation](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/grid.html):

- With `grid on` and `grid off`, you can show or hide a major grid.
- With `grid minor`, you *toggle the visibility of the minor grid lines*. This means that if a plot script containing `grid minor` is run multiple times, the minor grid will be shown or hidden depending on whether it was run an odd or even number of times. Is there a way to always show the minor grid, so without toggling? Something like `grid minor on`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `XMinorGrid`, `YMinorGrid` and `ZMinorGrid` properties of your axes to `'on'`.

```
surf(peaks)
set(gca,'XMinorGrid','on');
set(gca,'YMinorGrid','on');
set(gca,'ZMinorGrid','on');
```

[image: surf plot with minor ticks]