# Can I combine `grid on` and `grid minor` in one statement (Matlab)?

Tags: matlab, plot

(See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35335335/how-can-i-enable-the-minor-grid-lines-in-a-matlab-plot) for an explanation of the Matlab commands `grid on` and `grid minor`.)

I wondered whether it would be possible to combine both commands in something like `[grid on minor]`.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: Just out of curiosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot combine the two like that as `grid` only accepts one input argument.

Rather than using `grid` you could specify the [axes properties directly](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#zmw57dd0e50774) if you really want it to be a single command.

```
set(gca, 'GridLineStyle', '-', 'XMinorGrid', 'on', 'YMinorGrid', 'on', ...
         'ZMinorGrid', 'on', 'MinorGridLineStyle', ':')
```

Honestly though, it's more more legible and simple to just write two `grid` calls if this yields the desired result.

```
grid on
grid minor
```

Comment: Nice. Additionally, this removes the (possibly unwanted) toggling behaviour of `grid minor` (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35335335/how-can-i-enable-the-minor-grid-lines-in-a-matlab-plot)).

Comment: @Karlo Yes definitely. It's more work but it's also more explicit. See the link above to see all other grid-related axes properties.